# How to programatically add content-type as a row class in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that is displaying Full Content of several different content types, using the Masonry Views view module. I would like to add a class to each node display that is equal to the content type.

The template provided with the module is:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>

  <div class="masonry-item<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) print ' ' . $classes_array[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I can't figure out how to add the content type as a class, as I can't find that variable in the `$row`. How can i add the content type as a class to each item?

Comment: Maybe the `nid` is given?

Comment: what's the best way to get the content type from the nid?

Comment: Easiest way would be: `$node = node_load($nid); $node_type = $node->type;`. Are there more defined variables in your template?